# Is querying directly against tables somehow okay now?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

In the past, any database administrator worth his salt would have told you never to query against a table directly.  In fact, they would have prevented it by putting all tables in one schema & cutting-off direct access to that schema...thereby forcing you to query or CRUD from views & procedures etc. And further, protecting the data with security-layers like this made sense from a security perspective.

Now enters Entity Framework...

We use Entity Framework now where I work.  The IQueryable is King!  Everything is back into the DBO schema.  And, people are going directly to tables left-and-right because Repository patterns and online examples seem to encourage this very practice.

- Does Entity Framework do something under the hood that makes this practice okay now?
- If so, what does it do?
- Why is this okay now?

Help me understand.

Comment: Rather than vote to close this question.  Is there a place we can move it to?  I think this is a fair question to ask.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @jjj when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Does Entity Framework do something under the hood that makes this
  practice okay now?

EF doesn't really change the dynamic. It is a convenience of data access and rapid development, not a better way to get data.

- If so, what does it do?

It does not.  It does, I think, at least avoid constructing SELECT * type queries.

- Why is this okay now?

It remains a matter of opinion and culture. In general a "strict" DBA will want you to hit only exposed objects layered on top of the tables for CRUD. It is much easier to tune such queries and maintain control of performance if the application is using the expose custom objects rather than using an ORM or hand-coding direct queries.

IMO, ORM are great for rapid protyping and basic stuff, but anything with more complex logic or substantial performance should be moved to custom built objects.

Where/when that lines is will vary substantially based on any number of things including:

1. Size/load of database
2. Availability of database professionals vs app
   developers
3. Maturity of company

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of Entity Framework (Code First, Database First, Model First). It appears you have an issue with Code First, which creates the database based on your classes and limits what you can do on the database side of things.

However with EF Database First, you can still do everything you did before. You can restrict access to your tables and expose Stored Procedures/Views for your CRUD operations. You would still benefit from EF, because of the strongly typed classes that are generated from your Views, and strongly typed methods generated from your Stored Procedures.

Now everyone can be happy - you get to *cut off access to the schema* and  *IQueryable is still king*

Comment: I don't necessarily have an "issue" with EF itself.  I DO have an issue with not only how people use it, but how its use is "advertised".  The problem with something like EF is folks begin to treat is as more than a Rapid Prototyping tool...and they begin to think the "samples" are best practices...but they aren't.  Unless, of course, I am missing something (probably not).  Hence, the question.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - Based on your comment it appears you don't believe there are any benefits to using EF in a _robust_ application? You seem to be focussing solely on one aspect of what EF can do

Comment: Actually, I don't disagree with your comment.  I want to love EF.  I do.  But I also need some convincing :-)  So far, it "seems" to take a LOT of tinkering to make it work & the examples promote practices I used to get SCREAMED AT when I implemented them.  And to be fair...in retrospect...they were "right".  Many of these practices are tried, true & time-tested.  So, when folks drop these kinds of practices or promote tools that take a lot of tinkering and by-pass said practices...I just like to know why?  That's all there is to it really.